# Once Node.js is installed on Win10 why can I type node -v from any directory?

Tags: node.js

Step 1) Install `Node.js` on Windows 10 system

Step 2) Open `cmd.exe`

Step 3) `c:\Windows\System32>` shows up in console.

Step 4) type `node -v` and hit Enter

Result: `v9.2.0`

**Question**  I don't understand the mechanics of this. Why does `node -v` work from any directory on my system?  Why don't I need to be in the node directory running an `.exe` file to check the version number?  Once installed does `node.js` always run as some sort of background process?  Thanks so much for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer adds the node folder to the search path by appending the folder to the PATH environment variable.

https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the installation adds the directory in which your Node.js executable is found to your PATH environment variable. You can learn more about the PATH variable here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable).

Drats, just a few seconds slow in answering.